# If statement not hiding elements and showing elements when evaluated to true

Tags: jquery, html

I got into another problem with making a spy phone... The spy phone is password locked, and im gonna use obfuscate the jquery after this code gets fixed...
but the problem is, i have an if statement that checks for the value, sees if it is the correct password, but when i enter the correct password, nothing happens.

```
<!-- Spy phone-->
        <div id="spyphonectrl" style="position: fixed; top: 2%; right: 2%;">
            <button id="showspyphone" class="btn" style="color: white;">Hide/Show Spy Phone</button>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#spyphone").hide();
                    $("#showspyphone").click(function () {
                        $("#spyphone").toggle();
                        $("#spookystuff").hide();
                    });
                });
                $("#buttonthingy").click(function () { // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                    if ($("#loomynarty").val() == "DFF8GY8333") {
                        $("#loomynarty").hide(); // DOES NOT HIDE INPUT ELEMENT
                        $("#buttonthingy").hide(); // DOESN'T HIDE SUBMIT BUTTON
                        $("#spookystuff").show(); // DOESNT SHOW MAIN SPYPHONE STUFF
                    }
                });
</script>
            <div id="spyphone" class="spyphone">
                <p style="color: white;">Enter the code you got from passing the test.</p>

                <input type="text" id="loomynarty" style="width: 100px;">
                <button id="buttonthingy">Submit code</button>

                <div id="spookystuff">
            <button id="messagebutton"class="spyphonebutton">Messages</button>
            <div id="messages">
                <p>hai</p>
            </div>
            <button id="exit">Exit</button>
            <script>
                $("#messages").hide();
                $("#exit").hide();
                $("#messagebutton").click(function () {
                    $("#exit").show();
                    $("#messages").show();
                });
                $("#exit").click(function () {
                    if ($("#messages").is(":visible")) {
                        $("#messages").hide(); 
                        $("#exit").hide(); 
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
```

I suspect the problem at hand is actually checking the value, but I am not sure.

Comment: `#buttonthingy` does not exist at the time where you try to bind the click event handler – that part of code belongs into your `$(document).ready` function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found in the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/n0hwa0pu/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("input#loomynarty").val("DFF8GY8333");
var hideProblem = setInterval( function() {     
    if($("#loomynarty").length > 0 && $("input#loomynarty").val() === "DFF8GY8333")
    {
        $("#buttonthingy").css("background-color", "red");
        $("#buttonthingy").click(function () { // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            $("#loomynarty").hide(); // DOES NOT HIDE INPUT ELEMENT
            $("#buttonthingy").hide(); // DOESN'T HIDE SUBMIT BUTTON
            $("#spookystuff").show(); // DOESNT SHOW MAIN SPYPHONE STUFF
        //clearInterval(hideProblem);
        });  
    } else {
        var DoNothing = "";
    }
//return hideProblem;
}, 500);
```

});

I set the functionality inside of a setInterval() JavaScript function to check every 500 miliseconds if the parameter is true.  I added the background color on the button to visualy check if the code was even working and triggering.  This seemingly was just a case of bad syntax.  You can 'force stop' the script by uncommenting the clearInterval function so that it clears when all the hides have been done.